# How can artificially create a slow query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stress-testing

I'm giving a hands on presentation in a couple weeks. Part of this demo is for basic mysql trouble shooting including use of the slow query log. I've generated a database and installed our app but its a clean database and therefore difficult to generate enough problems.

I've tried the following to get queries in the slow query log:

Set slow query time to 1 second.

Deleted multiple indexes.

Stressed the system:

```
stress --cpu 100 --io 100 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout 1m
```

Scripted some basic webpage calls using wget.

None of this has generated slow queries. Is there another way of artificially stressing the database to generate problems? I don't have enough skills to write a complex Jmeter or other load generator. I'm hoping perhaps for something built into mysql or another linux trick beyond stress.

Comment: +1 For asking to get slow quries. If only it was this way around in real cases :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout [mysqlslap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html). You can pass one of your webapp's queries with --query and specify concurrent clients with --concurrency.

Comment: This worked best... using this and a combination of database de-tuning.

Answer (score 43):

Totally artificial but you can use the `sleep()` function:

```
select sleep(10);
```

In the log:

```
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 110629 16:19:13
# User@Host: mysql[mysql] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 10.000218  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1309389553;
select sleep(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... It does get the log to grow, but I'd like to have them be legit queries for the app. This way in I can demo explain and other diagnostic tools.

Comment: :) Hmm...maybe a strategic `LOCK TABLES` will work. That may be too kludgy as well.

Comment: Usually select * from ((select * from database)x) and keep getting more and more recrusive does the trick for me.

Comment: Use `DO SLEEP(10);`if you don't want the result of SLEEP in your query.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps de-tuning the database might help? For example reducing the key_buffers size?